# Bash: export .env variables

Tags: bash, dotenv

There is a rise of `.env` files ([nodejs community](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) & even [Python one](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/)).

They look like:

```
var1=val1
var2="val2 referencing ${var1}"
```

While there is special handling for `export`  prefix I wonder if it is possible to process `.env` file by Bash so it exports all definitions without file containing `export` keyword...

I can imaging rudimentary form (without proper handling of edge cases):

```
while read line; do
  case "$line" in
    "export "*=*) eval "$line";;
    *=*) eval "export $line";;
  esac
done <.env
```

Comment: You could just source the `.env` file right? `. test.env`

Comment: @0stone0 I could use `source`. The purpose is to *export values*. So local redefinitions are OK but they need to be exported too.

Comment: If I'm not wrong `set -a` will auto export variable. So if you `set -a` before `source` the file, they should be exported. Trying to find an explanation

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79064/how-to-export-variables-from-a-file/79077) and/or [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428175/how-to-export-all-bash-functions-in-a-file-in-one-line) unix stackexchange questions show how to export using source, or 'all' the defined variables.

Comment: @0stone0 Cool! I didn't know about `set -o allexport`.

Comment: Glad you've learned something new today ;) Sound like this already has been answered on SO, therefore I didn't post this as an answer. Still looking for a dupe.